# adding a multiple list attribute to product collection filter in magento

Tags: magento, collections, attributes, multi-select

I am trying to do an ajax related magento search, and i can't manage to correctly add a multi-select type product attribute to a product collection,
for instance:

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); //getting product model
$productCollection = $productModel->getCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(
                        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')
                            ->getProductAttributes()
                    );
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
             array(
                  array('attribute'=>'my_attribute_id', 
                          'finset' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                                        ->getAttribute('my_attribute_id')          
                                        ->getSource()
                                       ->getOptionId($searched))
                    );
```

where $searched is the string in which i save the keyword. Now, let's presume that my_attribute_id is a multi-select product attribute which has one option named as "Red Bull"...if i search after the exact string "red bull", it works, but i would like to work if i search only after "red" or "bull".
Is there a way to get the option id for an attribute, even if the search string is incomplete? Because the problem is here:

```
 Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getAttribute('my_attribute_id')
                        ->getSource()
                        ->getOptionId($searched))
```

this code returns the id of the attribute option only if i search it entirely.Probably the model does a query something like this

```
"select...where value='$searched'"
```

Is there a way to get a list of attribute option id's even if the value of the option is not complete?..so to do a query like this

```
"select...where value like '%$searched%'"
```

Or is there a better way to retrieve product collection after a multi-select attribute partial value, other then the solution that I am trying?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        'my_attribute_id',
        array(
            'like' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getAttribute('my_attribute_id')
                        ->getSource()
                        ->getOptionId($searched)
        )
    );
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...i added your suggestions, but did not work..
i forgot to mention in the original post that i have also the following code added:
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes());
anyway, i replaced my code with your suggestion but still nothing..